# How to write an NPAPI plugin with functionality of WScript.Shell

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser, npapi

I am very new to Web development, and have been writing some javascript that makes use of WScript.Shell via ActiveX. I am aware that browsers other than IE don't support ActiveX though.

After doing some digging through Google, I have discovered that I may be able to do something similar on all web kit based browsers via NPAPI. I have no idea where to even begin when it comes to this though. Is it possible to do what I am after via NPAPI? If so, where would I begin?

Comment: NPAPI is for browser plugins, not code on pages.

Comment: Would i be able to create a plugin to ship to my customers and have them install though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only care about Windows, you could simply use a NPAPI plugin to wrap the existing `WScript.Shell` - note however that plugins have to be embedded in the page; there is no equivalent for `new ActiveXObject("...")`. This also means you have to duplicate the scripting interface or write an automatic dispatcher for it.
For writing the plugin, take a look at the [FireBreath project](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) (disclaimer: i am its co-owner) which already gives you solutions for the most common tasks. If you want to do automatic dispatching for the scripting interface, take a look at [ff-activex-host's](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/) implementation (in particular `scriptable.h` and `axhost.cpp`).

Comment: I just built a plugin with FireBreath - took maybe 2 hours starting from scratch (the docs are a little... nonlinear) - I recommend the video tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do `new ActiveXObject`, your javascript can add an object tag to the DOM e.g.

```
var plugin = document.createElement('div');
plugin.innerHTML = "<OBJECT id='plugin0' blah blah blah ></OBJECT>";
document.body.appendChild(plugin);
```